# How to write data to MySQL table field(column) in PHP

Tags: php

I have MySQL table as websites, with three columns, one is serial number, second one is website and third one is contents. with the below script I'm able to loop through the website column and do some manipulation. Now I have output for each manipulation and I want to write this to contents column as soon as I manipulate.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wte");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Website FROM websites";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$website = $row["Website"];


$f = file_get_contents($website);

// How to write contents of $f to the Website row in my MySQL table?

}



    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: So you need to use a SQL UPDATE statement

Comment: `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO websites (Website) VALUES (" . $f . ")");` or if you want to update the existing rows then `$mysqli->query("UPDATE websites SET Website = '" . $f . "'");` or with a specific id this `$mysqli->query("UPDATE websites SET Website = '" . $f . "' WHERE id = " . $row['id']); `replace the id column name for the id of the table website and should work :)

Comment: @martinezjc  if I use the first query the data is not being sent to DB and same time no error when executing. If I use the update stmt with id then it throws error "Undefined index: S.No in C:\wamp\www\sample.php on line 38"

Comment: You need to add an INSERT statement into your code, the data can't magically appear in the database.